# How to use the `ColumnTransformer`?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the `ColumnTransformer` of scikitlearn.
Here's what I have :

```
median_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')
mean_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')

ct = ColumnTransformer([("LotFrontage", median_imputer, X_train.LotFrontage), ("MasVnrArea", median_imputer, X_train.MasVnrArea), ("GarageYrBlt", median_imputer, X_train.GarageYrBlt)])

imputed_X_train = pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(X_train))
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I get the following ValueError about the `fit_transform` function:
"No valid specification of the columns. Only a scalar, list or slice of all integers or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed"
What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing *the actual column data* for the third element of each triple (`X_train.LotFrontage` etc.).  You should instead pass the *name* of the column(s) [there are other options, see the docs], e.g.

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ("med_imp", median_imputer, ["LotFrontage", "MasVnrArea"]),
    ("mean_imp", mean_imputer, ["GarageYrBlt"])
])
```

(Since imputers operate on 2D inputs, you need to provide a *list* of columns.  And I've grouped two together and used your `mean_imputer` just to make the example a little more complex.)

Comment: And what is the use of the name ? for example where does "med_imp" come into play ?

Comment: From the documentation: "Like in Pipeline and FeatureUnion, this allows the transformer and its parameters to be set using set_params and searched in grid search."  You also get the fitted transformers available in `named_transformers_`, which is dictionary-esque, with those names as the keys.  Finally, `get_feature_names` prepends the transformed column names with the transformer names.